# for loop over sheets in a workbook with formulas until the end of a column with data

Tags: excel, vba

I have have the following problem with vba and would like to ask you for help.
I hope I haven't overseen a similar question in the froum

I have several sheets in an excel workbook. On each sheet I would like to run the same formulas. The formula gets its data from the cell C3 on the same sheet and should run until the end of the data in column C xxx . The length of the data is different on each sheet. Each sheet has its own data set.

The code I have written works fine in the sense that it works itself through through the sheets starting from sheet 2 until the end of the sheets.

The code gets executed via an icon in the toolbar.

On each sheet I have values what the formulas should use. The values in column C are different long. Some have for example just 15 some have over 300000.

For example, if I press the icon when I'm on sheet 1 with no data in column C the macro takes the first 15 values/range of the column for the formulas in all sheets. Which means I miss all values from for example at sheet 3 with 300000 values. If I am on sheet 3 and press the icon there I takes the 300000 values/range and uses the range of the 300000 values in all the other sheets.

If I run the code without the loop on each sheet it works fine. It selects the right range with values of the column.
There are no empty cells in the column.

Has anyone an idea what is wrong in the code that it does not select the real amount of values in column C for the different sheets?

I work on a mac with excel 14.

The following code is what I have so far:

```
Sub Start()

    Dim i As Long
    
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    
    With Sheets(i)
                .Range("K11").Formula = "=COUNT(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
                .Range("K12").Formula = "=MEDIAN(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
                .Range("K13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
                .Range("K14").Formula = "=MIN(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
                .Range("K15").Formula = "=MAX(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
                .Range("K16").Formula = "=STDEVP(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
       End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use .Cells to make it refer to the object in the With statement, otherwise it refers to the current sheet:

```
Sub Start()

    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = 2 To Worksheets.Count
    
        With Sheets(i)
            lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
            Debug.Print (i)
            Debug.Print (lastrow)
            .Range("K11").Formula = "=COUNT(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
            .Range("K12").Formula = "=MEDIAN(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
            .Range("K13").Formula = "=AVERAGE(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
            .Range("K14").Formula = "=MIN(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
            .Range("K15").Formula = "=MAX(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
            .Range("K16").Formula = "=STDEVP(C3:C" & lastrow & ")"
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tom Sharpe,
that works perfect
Thank you very much!